# terraform google monitoring alert policy filter a specific queue id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, filtering, alert, monitoring

I want to filter a specific cloud-task queue id but I cant figure it out
this is my code:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "cloud-tasks-slides-queue-is-too-large" {
    for_each = {for alert in local.metric_based_alerts: alert.displayname => alert}

    display_name = each.value.displayname
    combiner = "OR"
    conditions {
      display_name = "Condition"
      condition_threshold {
          filter          = "cloudtasks.googleapis.com/queue/depth"
          comparison      = each.value.comparison
          threshold_value = each.value.threshold_value
          duration        = each.value.duration
          trigger {
              count = 1
          }
      }
    }
    notification_channels = each.value.notification_channels
  }
```

Example of how i did it in the gui:
[image]

Thanks!